# Changing the SMS Limit - Cannot apply adb setting

Tags: android, adb

According to this [link](https://www.xda-developers.com/change-sms-limit-android/) it is possible to change the Android SMS rate limit with some adb commands without the need for root.

However, when I try one of the commands I get the following error

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denial: writing to settings requires:android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS
```

I am running Android 8.1 - is this no longer possible in this version of Android? I have a Xiaomi Poco F1 running MIUI 10 (in case it is specific to their ROM).

My phone is **NOT** rooted.

Comment: MIUI blocks a lot of ADB commands. There's another switch in Developer Options below the Debugging switch that has something to do with runtime permissions in ADB. Enable that.

Comment: @TheWanderer Thanks, that was it! If you add it as an answer I can mark it as the accepted answer. Just need to know if it had any affect now! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MIUI has another switch in Developer Options for ADB. It's somewhere below the USB Debugging toggle and might be called "USB Debugging (Security settings)". Turn that on.